# Plot only first 3 levels of C50 tree in R

Tags: r, plot, tree

The tree size of my `C5.0` output is around 90. When I plot it, I am not able to visualize it properly as they are sliding on each other. I got some code online where we can plot C5.0 tree from branches.

```
shoptree_forplot <- C50::as.party.C5.0(shoptree)
plot(shoptree_forplot[10])
```

This code plots a tree which are downwards from 10th level . It would be great it anybody can help me to plot only first 10 levels.

Comment: Can you tell us where you've found the code online? It's quite hard to reproduce your example without a better understanding what your objects look like.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198134/visualizing-c5-0-decision-tree
I found the code here